# C++ why is it allowed to assign to a reference to an abstract class?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have an abstract base class `Abstract` and a concrete class `Concrete` which is derived from `Abstract`. The following code is allowed:

```cpp
Concrete c1;
Concrete c2;
Abstract& a(c1);
a = c2;
```

A more involved demo of this shows that such an assignment results in data slicing:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Abstract {
public:
    virtual void f() const = 0;
  
protected:
    Abstract(int data) : _base_data(data) {}
    int _base_data;
};

class Concrete : public Abstract {
public:
    Concrete(int data) : Abstract(data), _derived_data(data) {}
    void f() const override { std::cout << _base_data << " " << _derived_data << std::endl; }
    
private:
    int _derived_data;
};

int main()
{
  Concrete c1(1);
  std::cout << "c1: ";
  c1.f();
  
  Concrete c2(2);
  std::cout << "c2: ";
  c2.f();
  
  Abstract& a(c1);
  std::cout << "a: ";
  a.f();
  
  a = c2;
  std::cout << "a (post-assignment): ";
  a.f();
}

// Output (GCC and Clang):
// c1: 1 1
// c2: 2 2
// a: 1 1
// a (post-assignment): 2 1
```

If this were with concrete derived and base classes, I would have assumed as much. But assignment (to me) seems closely related to instantiation, and `Abstract` can't be instantiated, so I erroneously assumed it couldn't be assigned to, either.

I can't think of a scenario where invoking the *implicit* assignment operator of an abstract class by *reference* is a valid thing to do that would result in expected behavior. Except, maybe as an implicit part of a derived class' implicit assignment operator, in which case it's by value and not by reference (I think).

If `Abstract` had no data members, then I think nothing would happen, and also no warning or error would be present. This seems like a specific and apparent enough case that *some* kind of measure could be in place from the language, but I don't even get a warning from Clang.

So is this a backwards compatibility thing? Maybe a compiler implementation thing? Is there an edge case that I'm not considering? Why is there not a rule forbidding this?

Comment: It's just a regular assignment operator. The fact that `a` is a reference does not change how its called. If you don't want a to be assigned to, you'll need to delete the assignment operator. You should also probably delete the copy constructor while you're at it.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I grant that, but the compiler has all the same information about what's happening here as I do, and I can tell this is fishy at best. That the language is as it is, doesn't mean there couldn't be some kind of special measure or diagnostic.

Comment: What would you expect to happen if `a` was a reference to an instance of `Concrete2` which is derived from `Abstract` but not from `Concrete`.     Assignment to `a = c2` in that case can only sensibly either do nothing or assign the `Abstract`-part.    Bear in mind that an abstract base class in C++ is permitted to have data members, so doing nothing does not make sense.

Comment: @Peter I would expect the compiler to give an error if any assignment to `Abstract` had been attempted. As I mentioned, assignment is in my mind related to instantiation and I expected it to follow similar limitations.

Comment: @squeevee - There's your problem.   Assignment has nothing to do with instantiation in C++.    The only possible connection is syntactic - an assignment token `=` can be used in initialisation (e.g.   `Class a = b`) but that is an alternate syntax for initialisation - it does not semantically do an assignment (e.g. calls a copy constructor, not an assignment operator).

Comment: @Peter and fair enough, that was a faulty logical extrapolation on my part. That doesn't change the core of the question, that this is a case that seems both easily detected by compiler (in at least a narrow form) and consistently wrong.

Comment: @squeevee - Contrary to your claim, it is not consistently wrong. It may be wrong in your particular (contrived) case.  Consistent with my previous comment, an assignment of the form `a = some_concrete2`  (where `some_concrete2` is an instance of a class derived from `Abstract` but not from `Concrete`) would sensibly only affect the "Abstract" part of `a` - because the common base class is the only thing in common between the two objects.    Not affecting the "Abstract part" would be inconsistent.  Diagnosing as an error, like you suggest, would be inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will auto-create copy constructors and `operator=` for every class you define, unless you explicitly tell it not to.  Doesn't matter if they're abstract.

```
class Abstract {
    Abstract& operator=(const Abstract& a) = delete;
};
```

Comment: It could matter though. My question is why doesn't it?

Comment: @squeevee because C++ tries to be consistent.  The fewer exceptions to the rules, the more sense the language makes - even if it sometimes results in undesirable outcomes.

Comment: Much though I agree that that is a part of the language's design philosophy, that is more or less speculation and not really an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given a class `A`, its assignment operator will assign only the `A` data members of one `A` object to another `A` object.

Given a class `B` that derives from `A`, a `B` object *is also* an `A` object.

If you have an `A&` reference (or an `A*` pointer) to a `B` object (which is perfectly valid, and required for polymorphism to work properly), the reference/pointer refers to the `A` portion of the `B` class, and so only the `A` members of the `B` object are accessible via that reference/pointer (to access the `B` members, you would need to type-cast the reference/pointer to `B&`/`B*` first).

A bound reference is just an alias to an object, so given a bound `A&` reference to a `B` object:

- assigning an `A` object to the `A&` reference will assign only to the `A` members of the `B` object.
- assigning the `A&` reference to another `A` object will assign only from the `A` members of the `B` object to the `A` members of the other object.

This is perfectly valid and legal, albeit not commonly used (outside of `B`'s own assignment operator, like you mentioned).  Assignments via base classes is rarely used in polymorphic types.  Derived class assignment operators or copy/move constructors are typically used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, as a compiled language, it ultimately points somewhere (even if that turns out to be nullptr or 0). Remember, too, that, ultimately, what you're doing is type casting, and C doesn't require you to cast, and you can straight up treat a void* as whatever you want within the language if you know what you're doing (and C++ comes from C).

As for why I might want to do this, imagine that I have a game with collision detection.  I might have a function that goes through all objects to determine if they connected with the player or not. Ultimately, all derived classes have to have a defined "check_if_touched_player()" or whatever I call it, so it's safe to rely on it. That's why it's declared virtual. The danger is if you try to use something that's specific to a class that isn't present, which virtual will not allow. I would argue the point that this is the entire reason behind virtual classes: to be able to make lists of dervied classes and "simply have them work" from an OOP perspective without necessarily knowing the details of the base class (after when they were first declared and assigned).

But, notice, it's not actually crashing in your example. The -S output from GCC should assist in rubber duck debugging what's really going on.

```
//Intel syntax because i hate GAS: -masm=intel
//this is a.f();
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-12] //Get the abstract class data that just got declared
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [eax] //Throw the reference in eax register
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [eax] //get the address of the overrided function
        sub     esp, 12
        push    DWORD PTR [ebp-12]
        call    eax //Actually call the function
        add     esp, 16 //Unclobber the stack
```

Hold the individual analysis of each line of assembly with a grain of salt, because completely unoptimized 32bit x86 assembly from GCC is a total pain to read. The important bit is the calling of a register (which means a variable location with a pointer presumably stored in it) rather than an specific, static address.

It's calling data that was stored. In other words, because you used virtual/override, it actually stores pointers to the functions, so as to actually pick the right one. A you can see, though, it went down a pretty long chain. The good news is this chain can be optimized (a little) using optimization flags, but keep in mind that his useful feature comes at that extra memory cost.

EDIT: This is also why you assign the virtual function as 0 (nullptr), so it crashes properly if somehow that data doesn't actually get initialized.